# How do you use the Facebook Graph API in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to access the information available when using the https://graph.facebok.com/id concept through JSON but have been unable to call or return any information based on different snippets of code I've found around. I'm not sure if I'm using the JSON function correctly or not.

For example,

```
var testlink = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/&callback=?";
   $.getJSON(testlink,function(json){
   var test;
  $.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
   test="<ul>"+json.name+"</ul>";
   });
});
```

In this code, I am trying to return in the test variable the name. When I use this in a Google Chrome Extension, it just returns a blank page.

Alternatively, I've been also trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK in my Google Chrome extension, but I am unsure what website I should be using when signing up for an API Key.

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery working properly in your extension?

Comment: if we build on what lees2bytes says, then we should be able to login using the method purposed here: http://sambro.is-super-awesome.com/2010/03/10/how-to-access-facebook-api-from-chrome-extension/#comments

please try this and let us know

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to establish either an OAuth session or provide your API key before you can talk to FB. It's been a while since I messed around with FB api but, I'm pretty sure you have to register before you can use the api.

Here's something that might be useful though, it's a javascript console for Facebook which would allow you to test out your code!  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with chrome, but I haven't figured out the exact problem.  For example open the chrome inspector and type this into it:

```
$.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/prettyklicks/feed?limit=15&callback=?", function(json){console.log(json);});
```

Then do the same thing in Firefox.  Chrome will return nothing, but FF will give you the JSON object.  It's not the JSON call itself because if you call something else for instance:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

It will come through normally.  So there is some miscommunication between chrome and fb. The really confusing part is that if you browse directly to the graph entry by just pasting it into your address bar it will come through normally that way too.

Comment: In this case, callback should be a string, which is a function name in your JS. 
it looks like, Firefox Eval the string and chrome does not.