# Error while trying to create a Facebook chat monitor google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create an extension for google chrome that will allow me to read a facebook page's conversations(messages). Right now, I'm having trouble with logging into facebook using chrome extension. I'm getting the error "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings." I don't have a clear idea on how to proceed. Can someone please point out what's wrong or can suggest a better alternative for reading a facebook page's conversations using Graph API in google chrome extension. Or is is possible as Firefox add-on?
This is the code I'm using

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "This plugin is showing how Facebook Connect/Graph API works on Chrome Extension.",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'",
"background": 
 {"page":"background.html"
 },
 "browser_action": {
 "default_popup": "popup.html",
 "default_icon":"icon.png"
 },
"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"http://*.facebook.com/*"
]
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</h1>
    <div id='status'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '197374294047884',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Connceted'
   // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
   // app, and response.authResponse supplies
   // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
   // request, and the time the access token 
   // and signed request each expire
   var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
   var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
   // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'not autorized'
   // but has not authenticated your app
   } else {
   // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'not connected'
   }
 });
};


(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  

});
```

Comment: You might want to check if your app properly implement OAuth 2.0 to access their API. Also here are some related SO question - [Facebook JavaScript API for google chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22728908/5995040), [How is it possible to use Facebook APIs with Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10210550/5995040) and [How do you use the Facebook Graph API in a Google Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5278932/5995040).

Comment: Lastly, here is a [tutorial](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) that shows an implementation of OAuth and Facebook, how to allow the access token url and configuring OAuth 2.0 endpoint. Hope this helps.